# Add-PnPPage : Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation. - Error received

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, app, aad

I have received `Add-PnPPage : Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.` error while running the command `$Page = Add-PnPPage -Name $pagename -LayoutType Article` even though I have been connected using the `Connect-PnPOnline` command and I have the SharePoint permission to the AAD App.

To me it seems that more permissions need to be granted in order to successfully run this command. What all other permissions need to be granted in this case?

Comment: What permissions you have on this site? You should have Edit/Full Control permissions on site.